# Windows Wave Out-capable USB device: What is Windows looking for?

Tags: windows, audio, usb

We build a custom audio device, basically a very specialized headset interface.

It was recently necessary to respin the hardware, as the old microcontroller is long since obsolete, End-Of-Life, defunct, GONE.

We also build a companion Java app, that works with this device and a non-Windows system we build.

The Java app uses a DLL to tie into the Windows USB audio subsystem.  At the end of one chain is a call to waveOutOpen(), to open a Wave Out-capable interface.

For reasons unknown to us, Windows apparently does not recognize our new hardware device as being Wave Out-capable.  The old device works fine.

We've (I've) looked very hard at the USB descriptors passed during enumeration.  I don't see any obvious critical differences.

What precisely is Windows looking for in the USB Audio descriptors, that tell it that the device is Wave Out-capable?